# What to use instead of "very small"?

Tags: vocabulary

I want to say

"the value of *a* is very small (almost zero)", or to say

"*a* is much smaller than *b*",

but I read that "very" and "small" doesn't make a fluent combination.
So, what else I could use instead of the above?

For example, "Considerably small" or "notably small"?

Comment: Who told you that "very small" isn't fluent? It sounds fine to me. Certainly better than your proposed alternatives.

Comment: @ThePhoton, well... it was suggested by "grammarly.com". It advises using "tiny" instead of "very small", but "tiny" doesn't fit the context!

Comment: Don't trust Grammarly.

Comment: @ThePhoton, that's why I put it here. :-D

Comment: "Negligible" might work in your context, but "very small" is also common in technical writing.

Comment: *Very small* is perfectly fine. If it's any smaller, try *infinitesimal*.

Comment: Your suggested replacements in the question's final sentence should be *considerably* ***smaller*** and *notably* ***smaller***. But I'll echo everybody else: there's nothing wrong with *very small*.

Comment: Itsy bitsy teeny tiny yellow polka dot bikini: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICkWjdQuK7Q

Answer (score 3):

The idea of being 'very small' can be expressed by adjectives *minute* and *infinitesimal*.

The latter one is more appropriate in your case.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary 
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infinitesimal :

***INFINITESIMAL***

: immeasurably or incalculably small

// an infinitesimal
difference

Answer (score 0):

You can say that *a* is ***[minuscule](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minuscule)***:

> **minuscule** *adjective*
>   \ ˈmi-nəs-ˌkyül\
>
> 2 : very small
>    *// minuscule* amounts
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minuscule)*</sub>

As you can see from the definition, however, "very small" is also a reasonable way to describe your thing.

(Note that it is often misspelled as "miniscule", probably on the presumption that it has *mini-* as a prefix driving the meaning of "small", but it is in fact derived from the Latin *minuscula*, "somewhat smaller".)

Answer (score -1):

well i believe you can say:
 a is microscopic compared to b.
 if you mean a and b as things but if a and b are in mathematics its better to use mathematical vocab like: 
a tends to zero while be tends to infinity.

or say the absolute opposite i mean:
b is astronomically huge compared to a.